# python webservice execution problem

Tags: python, web-services

I have a python web service. My problem is when I changed my web service classes. I can't see the changes on the browser and I see last version of web service on the browser all the time.
I used Bottle framework and cgi.

Comment: Please give more information about your web service (technology, logic ...)

Answer (score 0):

This is from my experience of using Django with Apache, but have you tried restarting your web server? Sometimes the web server will hold a copy of the  code in memory to speed up execution, but restarting your web server will make it reload all *.py files.

Providing more information about the technology stack you are using would help us help you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to restart the Bottle app after each change.  Doing this manually during development is a pain in the neck.  Fortunately Bottle provides a way to automate via a "reloader" option to the Run method:

> > > run(reloader=True)

When you edit & save a module file, the reloader will restart the server process for you.

Try it and let us know if it solves your problem!